# Graphically customize the Parse Login View

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xib, loginview

I watched the tutorial of Parse Login view (https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views). One thing I am wondering is how to customize those login view elements in .xib file graphically. For example, I want to put the LoginInWithFacebook button in a different place, or I want a smaller textField for inputing username.

Answer (score 1):

The Parse Login View is meant for very simple login screens that don't require a lot of customization. If you want to customize other aspects of the screen I would just build a new login view with everything the way you want it.